# place headline above and centered

Tags: html, css

I was given a suggention to improve my code. I  that suggention there is missing `<h1>` which I need.
The suggested code is work perfectly except from the missing h1.

My code is

```
<!--#include file="constants/dbopen.asp" -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Database</title>
</head>
<style>    
.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgb(2,0,36);
  background: linear-gradient(356deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,0.7455357142857143) 28%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}
.headline {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4400CC
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.image-and-text {
  max-width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-family: comic sans ms;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
<body class="body">
<br>
<h1 class="headline">Database</h1>
<%
Dim strSQL
strSQL = "SELECT filmid, titel, billede FROM film ORDER By Titel ASC"
Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
Response.Write("<div class='container'>")
If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
' No data
Else
Do While (Not rs.EOF)
Response.Write("<div class='image-and-text'>")
Response.Write "<img src='img/" & rs("billede") & "' class='image'/>"
Response.Write "<div>" & rs("titel") & "</div>"
Response.Write "</div>"
rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If
Response.Write("</div>")
%>
</body>
</html>
<!--#include file="constants/dbclose.asp" -->
```

I am trying to get the h1 text to be above my images and centered. I am new to the css world and is despertly needing some help.

Comment: firstly could you post the outputted html  instead. Also, you don't need a class for body, you can just do `body{ /*your styles here*/  }` .. as it's a native tag. Same for h1 tag, you can just use h1.. another native tag

Comment: How do you want me to post output? I have tried to style h1 with css, but I cannot get it above my images and centered.

Answer (score -1):

There is a `<center>` tag, which can center everything. HTML code is set to place elements by position in code, so as long as it's at the top of the Body tag, it'll stay at the top of the page. Not much css needed

Comment: the center tag is obsolete since html5 came in, and this tag should not be used